# How to write $ symbol to file using fwrite command in php

Tags: php, file, fwrite

Iam trying to create a file having an array declaration by using the following code. But the variable name is not coming to the resultant created page.

```
function createFile($fname,$code){
    $fp=fopen("products/".$fname,"w") or die("Can not open file");
    fwrite($fp,"<?php   
        $pageeInfo[productcode]=".$code.";
        ?>");

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes inhibit variable interpolation.

```
'$'
```

But don't write self-modifying code; use a database of some sort instead.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to accomplish this is to use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php):

```
function createFile($fname, $code)
{
    return file_put_contents(
        "products/".$fname, // filename
        '<?php $pageInfo = ' // start tag
        .var_export(array( // we export an array
            'productcode' => $code,
            // add more keys if needed here
        ), true)
        .';' // end tag is not required
    );
}
```

Comment: No, the proper way to accomplish this is to use a database. But `var_export()` may work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are nesting php tags. You might try taking the nested php tags out.

```
function createFile($fname,$code){
    $fp=fopen("products/".$fname,"w") or die("Can not open file");
    fwrite($fp, $pageeInfo[productcode].'='.$code);
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and suggestion, But aim is to create a php file and each php file must contain an array . I mean I would like to solve the problem in the creation of a php file using the fwrite command. Please help me